# How to get EditContext.Validate() to work when binding EditForm to an array

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I created an `EditForm` wrapping a table like so:

```
**Index.razor**


@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<EditForm @ref="Form" Model="vms" OnSubmit="Submit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var vm in vms)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <InputText @bind-Value="vm.Code"></InputText>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => vm.Code)"></ValidationMessage>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
</EditForm>

@code{
    List<MyClass> vms;
    EditForm Form;
    class MyClass
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Required")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        vms = new List<MyClass>()
    {
            new MyClass()
            {
                Code = "1111"
            },
            new MyClass()
            {
                Code = "2222"
            }
        };
    }
    private void Submit()
    {
        bool IsValid = Form.EditContext.Validate();
    }
}
```

The message error pops correctly as per the below image:

[image]

However, when I submit the form and then validate, it does not seem to pick up the invalid state.

[image]

It is still returning true after calling `EditContext.Validate()`, even though there are errors.

How do I get this to work? (How do I get false when at least one of the model item in the EditForm context is invalid so I can do my other validation stuff?)

---

[Updated 2021-01-16]
Answers can also be found here.
https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/validating-complex-models-in-blazor/

In short, the built-in DataAnnotationValidation does not work with arrays.
To get it working, you must

1. installMicrosoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation
2. Make the array an attribute and then decorate it with [ValidateComplexType]
3. Use ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator

Comment: According to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0, you should create a new EditContext in the OnInitialized() routine for the form (editContext = new EditContext(vms).  Maybe this would help you

Comment: I agree with @JasonD , then when you what to validate you could use :
if (editContext .Validate()) {//SomeLogic}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, I'd suggest you do something like this

```
<EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnSubmit="Submit">
```

Instead of

```
<EditForm @ref="Form" Model="vms" OnSubmit="Submit">
```

Which requires you to define  EditContext like this:  `EditContext editContext;`

And instantiate the  EditContext object in the OnInitialized method like this:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        vms = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass() { Code = "1111" },
                                    new MyClass() { Code = "2222" }
                                  };

        editContext = new EditContext(vms);
    }
```

Incidentally, why do you use `OnSubmit` instead of `OnValidSubmit` and `OnInvalidSubmit` ? Are you looking for challenges ?

> EditContext.Validate() returns incorrect results

That is not true...

The issue is that you try to bind to an array of MyClass...But you should bind to a single object. Binding to an array is possible, but I can't extend on it as it merits a new question. Suffice it to say that the array of objects you can bind to must be itself a field (property) of an a single bounded object, as for instance, a Student object that contains a list of Languages he speaks.

In order to verify the above, change `List<MyClass> vms;`

into `MyClass model = new MyClass();`

and `editContext = new EditContext(vms);`

into `editContext = new EditContext(model);`

and instead of

```
 @foreach (var vm in vms)
  {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <InputText @bind-Value="vm.Code"></InputText>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => vm.Code)"> 
       </ValidationMessage>
                </td>
            </tr>
  }
```

code this:

```
<tr>
     <td>
        <InputText @bind-Value="model.Code"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.Code)"></ValidationMessage>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

Now, run your code, and verify whether the defamation of the `EditContext.Validate()` was justified.

### Update

The following code sample describes how to bind to a collection in an EditForm, and how to validate this collection as well as other fields in a model of which this collection is a field member.

Note: You should execute `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation -Version 3.2.0-rc1.20223.4` in your Package ManagerConsole, to access objects necessary to make the sample work...

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<EditForm EditContext="EditContext" OnSubmit="@OnSubmitHandler">
    @*<DataAnnotationsValidator />*@
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator/>
    <p>
        <label for="name">Enter name: </label>
        <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="customer.Name" /><br />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => customer.Name)" />
    </p>
    @foreach (var phone in customer.phones)
    {
<p>
    <label>Enter phone: </label>
    <InputText @bind-Value="phone.PhoneNumber" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => phone.PhoneNumber)" />
</p>
    }

    <p>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </p>

</EditForm>

<div>
    <p>Edit  customer</p>

    <p>@customer.Name</p>
    @foreach (var phone in customer.phones)
    {
        <p>@phone.PhoneNumber</p>

    }

</div>
<div>
     <p>Is model validated: @validated.ToString()</p>
 </div>
@code {
    EditContext EditContext;
    Customer customer;
    bool validated;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        customer = new Customer();
        EditContext = new EditContext(customer);

    }
    private void OnSubmitHandler()
    {            
        validated = EditContext.Validate();
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }  
        [ValidateComplexType]
        public List<Phone> phones { get; set; } = new List<Phone>() { new Phone { }, new Phone { }, new Phone { }};
         
    }

    public class Phone
    {
        [Required]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However the struggle I am having is that I want to achieve the following two things at the same time: 1. Bind to a list 2. Make EditContext.Validate() work. I tried your suggest of creating a wrapper class and then include the list of MyClass into the wrapper as a property, but data annotation stops working after I do that. Perhaps I should word my questions better, like "How to get EditContext.Validate() to work while binding EditForm to an array".

Comment: See Update section in my answer. Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Comment: "Incidentally, why do you use OnSubmit instead of OnValidSubmit and OnInvalidSubmit? Are you looking for challenges?"

This is now my favorite comment of my career... I'm enjoying the answer too well.